# How to persistent the child screen (with Navigator.push()) on bottom navigation bar changed

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Is there any way to persistent/keep alive the child screen `(with Navigator.push())` on bottom navigation bar changed.

Example screen with bottom navigation

1. Screen A
2. Screen B
3. Screen C

Screen A has a button to open child screen example called it `Screen Child A`
now trying to move/ change screen with bottom navigation to Screen B or C and back to Screen A. when back `Screen Child A` will disappear , what i expecting is to keep it alive

example like `Instagram`.

Comment: Include your code please

Comment: Please, use iOS terminology. It is a bit hard to parse your query. And post some code!